# Disable primary terminal console login?

Tags: ssh, login

I noticed that ssh you by default have root login disabled, and in this question we will assume one has activated the root account, so a user can use 'su' to gain access to root, but they cant use 'sudo'. This way root is protected by two passwords. One for the unknown user, and the second time for the root account via su.

Okay so I noticed even though ssh it's disabled to directly login as root, I wondered if there is also a way to disable the terminal of the VM console from having a login prompt all together or just for the root account like ssh_config allows.

One thought was is there a different bashrc startup script for login from the terminal that could include an exit command, and then a different one if you use 'su' from another account.

Otherwise I figure it must be paranoid to think that a hacker can get to the VM terminal as it is impossible, or basically they have the bare metal, and really they still need the root password.

It seems like a pointless question, but I am guessing there is a way to just run headless and the VM has no login prompt but ssh still works, or something better like blocking the root user from the VMs primary terminal/console login prompt.

Comment: `sudo systemctl mask getty@.service` will prevent systemd from spawning getty on TTYs, but having physical access will always enable an attacker do directly drop to a root shell, even if the root account is disabled. The only way to force a password at startup is disk encryption.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. Is there a grub file option to disable the terminal? I noted some options about turning off Graphical version but I run Ubuntu Server (19.04) at this time anyway.

Comment: I was wondering how one might unmask it? Oh wait it is unmaskable just fine. It's very strange there is no status for it?! I tried getty@.services plural with an 's' at the end and thought that was my mistake but that's nothing...? or is it? Maybe there's an agetty flag or inittab or something else to consider otherwise.

Comment: `getty@.service` is a template. The actual instances are `getty@tty1.service` etc, depending on the tty it is spawned on.

Comment: Okay great I looked it up https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html and found it here /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service so thanks again for the lesson in systemd templates